# how to add image on python pyqt5

Tags: python, image, pyqt5

I have problem with the image is not drawn in gui. I dont understand. I want a picture to be drawn on my label.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1022, 748)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.imge = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.imge.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 901, 511))
    
 
 
        self.imge.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("__jet_pack_man_with_weapon_flying.png"))
        self.imge.setScaledContents(True)
        self.imge.setObjectName("imge")
        self.imge.show()
        self.previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.previous.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 560, 241, 91))
        self.previous.setObjectName("previous")
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 560, 261, 91))
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1022, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.previous.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Previous"))
    self.next.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name is correct and the image file is not corrupted? Is the file in the same path of the script you're running, and are you running python from *that* path?

Comment: use image fullpath

Comment: Image is in folder with this code. What is fullpath????How to use it.